# How to Reduce Number of Variables Before Running Random Forrest or XGBoost

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, dimensionality-reduction, boosting

I've simplified the problem I'm working on for this post, so that the focus is on the issue I'm having.

I'm trying to predict if a patient will be diagnosed with arthritis in 2019, based on the ICD-10 diagnosis codes found on claims in 2018. My strategy was to build a model off of a training set based on 2017 claims, with a target variable that indicates if the patient had arthritis in 2018. I would then score patients based on their 2018 claims.

Below is a screenshot of the way I wanted to structure my data, with some made up diagnosis data.

[image: View of Table]

Patient ID  Arthritis_Ind   Age Gender  Diag_A00_Ind    Diag_A000_Ind   Diag_A001_Ind   […]

100000001   0   75  F   0   0   1   […]

100000002   0   60  M   0   0   0   […]

100000003   1   71  F   0   1   0   […]

100000004   0   80  M   1   0   0   […]

100000005   0   91  F   0   0   0   […]

[…] […] […] […] […] […] […] […]

The columns in my table are as follows:

Patient ID: Uniquely identifies a patient. There will be one row for one patient.

Arthritis_Ind: Indicates of the patient was diagnosed with arthritis in 2018, with a 1 or 0.

Age: Patient age (Integer).

Gender: Patient gender (M or F).

Diag_XX_Ind: An indicator variable, 1 or 0, that indicates that a member received a diagnosis at sometime in 2017, where XX represents an ICD-10 diagnosis code.

The problem is, there are 18,000 ICD-10 diagnosis codes, and I have data on hundreds of thousands of patients. I'm running into memory issues creating a table with this many columns and creating a random forest or xgboost model off of it.

I strongly suspect that, at most, only a few dozen ICD-10 diagnosis codes will predict if a patient has arthritis. Any advice as to how I can reduce the list of 18,000 potential ICD-10 diagnosis codes down to a more manageable number, before creating a random forest or xgboost model? Are there any methods I could use to reduce the number of variables before hand? Should I restructure my data in some way? Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Aside looking at dimensionality reduction techniques, is sparse encoding used for this data? Also how big is your computer in terms of RAM?

Comment: My computer has 8 GB of RAM. The claims data currently sits on a SQL server. My original plan was to write a SQL query, structuring the data in the way indicated in my original question, and save the results on my computer. I would then build a model on my computer using the randomForest or xgboost packages in R. However, I'm running into an issue where I cannot even create a SQL table with more than 2048 column of data, but the number of columns I'm trying to create is much higher than this, so I'm not quite getting to the point where I can do sparse encoding.

Comment: So you want the dimensionality reduction to happen within SQL? Consider extracting smaller chunks and then combining as sparse. The fact you cannot even create an SQL table kind off kills most in-memory options.

Comment: I was also thinking that it might make more sense to restructure my data. Having it in a format where I have 18,000 indicator variables seems unwieldy. Restructuring it so that it only has 5 columns (patient ID, Arthritis_Ind, Age, Gender, ICD-10 Diag) seems more manageable, but then I run into the issue where patients could receive more than one diagnosis, so each row would no longer represent a single observation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems that most of your problems hinge on SQL and the computer that you're using. If you extract the data from SQL and then do all of your transformations on a larger computer (perhaps using a cloud provider like AWS or Google Cloud), all that's left is spending the time to fit the model, no feature selection needed. If you insist on using SQL to do pre-processing, then the question reduces to "what variable selection methods can I do in SQL" which is not an on-topic question.

Comment: @Sycorax: I think we can have a solution to the OP. as this is a case where the "traditional" one-hot encoding fais. Off the bet, I would suggest that the OP considers doing binary encoding of categorical features.

Comment: Why not use substantive knowledge to drop a lot of columns and combine others?

Comment: @Sycorax I think there are alternatives to the SQL solution that may be on-topic.

Comment: Is prediction what we care here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution to this problem, and wanted to post here in case anyone else found it helpful. Comments by usεr11852 about sparse encoding helped point me in the right direction.

My strategy was as follows.

1) Restructure my SQL pull in a long format, to avoid the column issue I was facing in SQL. See example below:
Patient_ID,Var,Val

100000001,_Arthritis_Ind,0

100000001,Age,75

100000001,Diag_A001_Ind,1

100000002,_Arthritis_Ind,0

100000002,Age,60

100000003,_Arthritis_Ind,0

100000003,Age,71

100000003,Diag_A000_Ind,1

etc...

2) Use the sparseMatrix function in the R package Matrix to reshape the data from long into wide format. Because the matrix is extremely sparse, I didn't run into memory issues. The method is described at this link:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/casting-a-wide-and-sparse-matrix-in-r/

3) Run xgboost, with _Arthritis_Ind as my target variable, which ran without issues.

Comment: Smart move! And good on you for sharing this back! (+1) (I guess you can also accept your own answer but that will not give you any rep points.)

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the most simple possible solution, and only if that doesn't work I'd start to look into more complicated options.

The first place to start when you wish to reduce the number of variables in your data is principal components analysis (PCA). This looks for new features that are linear combinations of your old features, and summarize your dataset, minimizing the information lost in the process. If your data is sparse (you said that the ICD-10 codes are just ones and zeros), the chances are that just a few PCA features (called *principal components*) will summarize your dataset well.

PCA is implemented out-of-the box in scikit-learn. You can import it with `sklearn.decomposition.PCA`, train it with `pca = PCA(n_components=q).fit(X_train)` and use it on your train or test data with `pca.transform(X_train_or_test)`.

I would keep the rest of your features, run PCA just on the ICD-10 codes and find a few tens or hundreds of principal components for the ICD-10 codes. In scikit-learn, you can choose the number of principal components by looking at the `pca.explained_variance_ratio_`. An accumulated explained variance ratio of 0 explains nothing of your dataset, and a ratio of 1 explains everything.

Good luck!

(**Gist of PCA**)

If $\mathbf{X}$ is your data matrix (called the *design matrix*, with $N$ samples along the row dimension and $p$ features along the column dimension), PCA finds the $q$ principal components $\mathbf{v}$, $q \leq p$, that most minimize the difference between $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Xvv}^\text{T}$.

$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
    \mathbf{v^*} = \argmin_\mathbf{v} \;\;\lVert \mathbf{X} - \mathbf{Xvv}^\text{T} \rVert^2,
$$

where $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is the Frobenius norm (essentially the same as the $L2$ norm but for matrices). Notice that if $\mathbf{v}$ is an unit vector that specifies a direction, $\mathbf{Xvv}^\text{T}$ is simply the reconstruction of $\mathbf{X}$ along that direction. So PCA is finding the directions with the most information!

(**End of gist of PCA**)

Comment: PCA reduces the number of features that you hand off to the classification algorithm but it has some considerable drawbacks. First, you must retain all of your original features in order to apply PCA to the data to hand it off to the model. Second, your new features are more challenging to interpret because they are linear combinations of all of your original features. Third, a feature which may be predictive in the original space may be so deformed by PCA that its signal is lost. A more useful method would attempt to screen irrelevant features entirely from the data set.

Comment: Hi Sycorax. Of course every method comes with advantages and disadvantages. However, PCA is found to work well in practice in many, many problems, which is why it is so popular. Regarding the concerns that you raise, first, I would guess that PCA uses less memory than training random forests, so it could not be a problem that you apply it to all the features. Second, because they are linear combinations of the original features, you can always map how much of each original feature is in the principal components, so PCA is one of the most interpretable feature reduction methods.

Comment: And third, sometimes PCA can actually help! Sometimes it is the original features that represent some distorted "hidden" feature, and PCA helps you find it :)

Comment: (1) You've already committed to loading your original data, and then on top of that you're creating new matrices to map from the original data to the PCA space. OP has stated that memory consumption is the problem to solve; PCA makes that problem worse. (2) Reversing PCA and interpreting a model are not the same thing. It's easy to understand what a single-feature split in a tree means; it's harder to understand what a linear combination of 18000 features being larger/smaller than a constant means except abstractly. Likewise interpreting importance rankings of PCs versus original features.

Comment: (3) OP can't run the non-PCA'd model due to memory constraints, so if PCA removes signal, he'd never be able to verify that the non-transformed data contained signal. The failure mode is pernicious, and must be acknowledged as a risk.

Comment: Hi again Sycorax:

Comment: Ups, seems that I cannot edit that comment anymore! Sorry, newbie mistakes... (1) I'm not sure doing PCA would be undoable on 8GB... You have to compute the eigenvectors of the covariance X^T X, which is p x p (p is the number of dimensions). For instance, there is an answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/how-to-do-svd-and-pca-with-big-data) saying that you should be able to do PCA up to 20000 variables on 8GB of memory. I haven't run the experiment but that estimation doesn't sound too much of a stretch to me...

Comment: (2) Well, interpretability is a very subjective thing :) Depending on the problem, mapping back to the original features may be all that you need. And this is why PCA is taught to be interpretable in comparison with other dimensionality reduction techniques., as opposed to for instance t-SNE or UMAP.

Comment: (3) I think you would have this risk with every dimensionality reduction technique! :) If you use the technique to reduce variables because you don't have enough memory, you are never gonna be able to look at what the performance of your algorithm would have been in the original space, but that shouldn't hold you from trying your model in the smaller spaces that you can afford to work on. In fact, one of the stereotypical examples of application for dimensionality reduction is reducing memory usage.

Comment: But as with many other situations in statistics/machine learning, applying PCA, t-SNE, UMAP, etc, or in fact choosing any model over another, is sometimes more of an art than a science, so it may or may not be that PCA works well in this particular case. The only thing I'm saying is that if I had to try something first, I would go for the simplest possible solution to begin with, and in my humble opinion the simplest solution is PCA :)